# Python Code Error using Twitter Rest API

Tags: python, twitter

Hi I have an assignment due using the Twitter Rest API. For some reason my get_user_profile function is not defined, and I was wondering why that is the case. Thanks in advance!

```
import twitter

def oauth_login():

    CONSUMER_KEY='***'
    CONSUMER_SECRET='**'
    OAUTH_TOKEN='***'
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET='***'

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)

twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)
def get_user_profile(twitter_api, screen_names=None, user_ids=None):
        assert (screen_names !=None) != (uder_ids !=None), \
        "Must have screen_names or user_ids, but not both"

        items_to_info = {}

        items = screen_names or user_ids

        while len(items) > 0:
            items_str = ",".join([str(item) for item in items[:100]])
            items = items[100:]

            if screen_names:
                response = make_twitter_request(twitter_api.users.lookup, screen_name=items_str)

            else:
                response = make_twitter_request(twitter_api.users.lookup, user_id=items_str)

            for user_info in response:
                if screen_names:
                    items_to_info[user_info['screen_name']] = user_info
                else:
                    items_to_info[user_info['id']] = user_info

        return items_to_info


    #get user profile (9.17) get friends followers ids (9.19) 9.22S
return twitter_api
```

twitter_api=oauth_login()
    print twitter_api
    print get_user_profile(twitter_api, screen_names=["max_herbowy"])

Comment: Can you double check the indentations in your code sample? It is hard to tell what is actually nested and what isn't. It's kind of important when debugging Python code.

Comment: The indentation is definitely screwed up in the code: while oauth_login() has only 4 spaces the get_user_profile() has 8 initial spaces as indentation. This of course doesn't reflect the actual indentation of the original code but I guess the problem is a mixture of space-based and tab-based indentation in the original code. I would recommend using an editor that can display whitespace characters and trun on showing whitespaces (good examples: Visual Studio with python plugin or simply Notepad++). I would recommend using just tab characters to indent python code.

Comment: Can you share with us the actual exception of the code?